# Lemma from paper on Elementary equivalence of profinite groups by Jarden & Lubotzky

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

In Jarden's and Lubotzky's paper  ['Elementary equivalence of
profinite groups'](http://132.64.72.10/%7Ealexlub/PAPERS/Elementary%20equivalence%20of%20profinite%20groups/Elementary%20equivalence%20of%20profinite%20groups.pdf) Lemma 1.1 on page 3 the proof starts with a reduction step I
not understand at all. The lemma is:

*Lemma 1.1: For each positive integer $n$ and each finite group $A$ of
order at most $n$ there exists a sentence $ \theta $ of
$\mathcal{L} \text{(group)} $
such that for every group $G$ of order at most $n$
the sentence $ \theta $ holds in $G$ if and only if $A$ is a quotient of $G$.* $\tag{L}$

*Proof*: The proof is based on verification of a seemingly weaker claim:

It suffices to prove that for every positive integer $n$ and
for every group $A$ of
order $d$ dividing $n$ there exists a sentence $ \theta $ of
$\mathcal{L} \text{(group)} $ with the following property:
for every group $G$ of order $n$ the sentence $ \theta $ holds in $G$
if and only if $G$ has a normal
subgroup $M$ such that $G/M \cong A$. [..]    $\tag{L'}$

Why is it sufficient to prove the claim (L') which is seemingly weaker as the claim of the lemma (L)? The claim of
the lemma immediately imply the second claim, the reverse implication
is not clear.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is a rather silly way to go about things in the first place. As long as we're in a finite language, for any class of finite structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and any $n$ there is a first-order sentence $\theta$ such that for every structure $\mathcal{S}$ of size $\le n$ we have $\mathcal{S}\models\theta$ iff $\mathcal{S}\in\mathfrak{A}$.Now just take $n$ to be the $n$ of the lemma and take $\mathfrak{A}$ to be the class of all finite groups of which $A$ is a quotient.

Comment: yes, you are right, if we know this more general fact on finite languages you quoted above, then the proof is a one liner. But my question related more to the internal structure of this proof: why, if we know (L') is true, then (L) is a consequence of (L').